# Completely remove Darknet network from memory

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

I am trying to run many instances of `yolo-darknet` network on my `Jetson-Nano`, but they all can't work on Nano at the same time, because of higher memory requirement than what's available on Nano.

I did `grpc` server which gets a batch of images and loads network in memory. After calculating, I am releasing memory with `free_network(network *net)` method.

It works, but every second call of this method releases some 50-70 mb less memory than what was loaded in memory. When I operate with batch of images, this does not continue indefinitely, approximately after 20 iterations usage of memory stop growing.

I tested it without calculating as well, just load network and free from memory but I had the same issue.

How can I completely remove/free network from memory without killing the process?

Answer (score 1):

There was some known bug like [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/4841#issuecomment-631177987) related to `gpu` memory leak with `darknet` and it has been already [fixed](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/commit/03eee3092f5084fd58b97cba8d1734db2f29022b). If you've not updated the code yet and using older versions, I suggest you to pull the latest [code](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) and run.

If that doesn't fix your issue, there was another [bug](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/6196) reported for gpu memory leak along with possible fixes, see if that helps.